# Boot options menu disappeared

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, menu

I had *Windows 7* and *Ubuntu* both installed on my machine, but for some reasons I re-installed Windows 7, and now when the system starts, I can't see GRUB menu, which normally appears asking using for windows or ubuntu OS.

How to bring that menu back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should definitively have be asked before, but cannot find a reference.

By the way, it is a normal situation, answered [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstalled windows, now you have its bootloader which conveniently doesn't detect Linux OS's, and not Grub.

To reinstall Grub, with all the options you had, you'll need a linux live CD or pen.
Once in a "live session":

1. Open a Terminal
2. Use `sudo fdisk -l` and locate Ubuntu's partition.
3. Mount said partition in `/mnt` (replace XY, with the correct letter & number):

   - `sudo mount /dev/sdaXY /mnt`
4. Reinstall grub (assuming /dev/sda is your main HDD):

   - `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`